# Catchall target with BSD's make

Tags: makefile, bsdmake

In a BSD Makefile, is it possible to define a catch-all target? I'm looking for the GNU equivalent of:

```
%:
    @echo caught target $@
```

I was hoping that the preprocessor possesses enough magic to define a target on the fly, but couldn't figure out how to do so. All local variables, such as `.TARGET`, only work *within* a target but not at global scope.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if BSD make qualifies, but every POSIX-compliant version of make must support the `.DEFAULT:` special target which does this, even in GNU make, without the overhead of using a catch-all pattern like `%`:

```
.DEFAULT:
        @echo caught target $@
```